# React Native Hot Reloading not working on IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm making a React Native app. And debugging or working with it, it get very tedious day by day due to the time it takes to reload the app every single time with Command+R to refresh and see my changes.

I found that is possible to do Live Reload/Hot Reload. But is not working for me.

Every time I do a change on my code, shows up the "Hot Loading..." above, but you can wait 20 minutes and it won't reload anything.

What could be wrong here? Let me know what to check and I can edit this post.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem. Solved running:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman && brew uninstall watchman && brew install watchman
```

From this [comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10889#issuecomment-260978635).

Comment: Mmm, not yet.. i could make Live Reload work, but Hot Reloading still isn't working. :(

Comment: msqar, What is your react native version? If you init a new react native project hot reload works?

Comment: Actually i tried to use hot reload almost at the very beginning, and i couldn't make it work, i just kicked the issue for later, but now that my app gets larger, it was very tedious, thank God that live reload works now, but it wasn't working before. My react versions are `"react": "^16.0.0-alpha.6"` and `"react-native": "^0.44.0"`.